# Can't navigate from inside drawer in Navigation 5 using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, expo

Hi I can't seem to navigate to the other screen using the options code stated below, does anyone know why this wouldn't be working? I'm also getting an error stating "Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle." but I don't think this is causing the problem as the navigation works properly anyway and every time I click one of the buttons on the navigation it doesn't even give me an error or anything.

Tab Navigation / Main Screen after use login

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const UserNavigator = () => (

<Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
    activeTintColor: 'black',
    inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
    tabStyle: {borderColor:'grey', borderWidth:0.5,},
    style: {
        backgroundColor: 'lightblue'}}}  >
 <Tab.Screen 
 name="Feed" 
 component={FeedNavigator}
 options= {{
     tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) =>
     <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
    }}/>
 
 <Tab.Screen 
 name="Account" 
 component={AccountNavigator} 
 options= {{
     tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) =>
     <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
    }}/>
 
 <Tab.Screen 
 name="Settings" 
 component={SettingsNavigator} 
 options= {{
     tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) =>
     <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cog-outline" color={color} size={size} />
    }}/>

 </Tab.Navigator>
```

Drawer Content

```
export function DrawerContent({props}) {
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1, top: 25}}>
                <View style={styles.drawerContent}>
                <View style={styles.userInfoSection}>
                        <View style={{flexDirection:'row',marginTop: 15,}}>
                            <Avatar.Image 
                                source={{
                                    uri: 'https://scontent-lcy1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/66377084_2811566162247295_7686084060568879104_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_ohc=Xy7R59FbVcgAX-Xknlk&_nc_ht=scontent-lcy1-1.xx&oh=4502184d110eb6cf3e57db98063f1e29&oe=6092F725'
                                }}
                                size={50}
                            />
                            <View style={{marginLeft:15, flexDirection:'column'}}>
                                <Title style={styles.title}>Marc Brolly</Title>
                                <Caption style={styles.caption}>@brolly301</Caption>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.row}>
                            <View style={styles.section}>
                                <Paragraph style={[styles.paragraph, styles.caption2]}>120</Paragraph>
                                <Caption style={styles.caption2}>Artists Followed</Caption>
                            </View>
                        </View>

                 <Drawer.Section style={styles.drawerSection}>
                  <DrawerItem 
                icon={({color, size}) => (
                    <Icon name="home-outline"
                    color={color}
                    size={size}
                    onPress={() => {}}/>
                )}
                label="Home"/>
                
                </Drawer.Section>    
                 
                 <Drawer.Section style={styles.drawerSection}>
                  <DrawerItem 
                icon={({color, size}) => (
                    <Icon name="account-outline"
                    color={color}
                    size={size}
                    onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('Account')}}/>
                )}
                label="Profile"/>
```

Main Auth Navigator

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthNavigator = () => (

<Stack.Navigator>

<Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={LoginPage} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
<Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegistrationForm} 
options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'lightblue'}, 
headerTitle: (
    <View style={styles.logo}>
       <Image style={styles.logo} source={require("../assets/logo.png")}/>
    </View>),
headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center', top: 0,  },
headerRight: () => (
    <Icon style={styles.icon} 
      name="help-circle-outline"  
      size={80}
      iconColor="black"/>) }}/>

<Stack.Screen name="UserNav" component={DrawerNavigator} 
options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'lightblue'}, 
headerTitle: (
    <View style={styles.logo}>
       <Image style={styles.logo} source={require("../assets/logo.png")}/>
    </View>),
headerShown: false}}/>  

<Stack.Screen name="ForgotPass" component={ForgotPassNav} options={{ headerShown: false }}
options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'lightblue'}, 
headerTitle: (
    <View style={styles.logo}>
       <Image style={styles.logo} source={require("../assets/logo.png")}/>
    </View>),
headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center', top: 0,  },
headerRight: () => (
    <Icon style={styles.icon} 
      name="help-circle-outline"  
      size={0}
      iconColor="black"/>) }}/>

<Stack.Screen name="Confirm" component={ForgotPasswordConfirmation} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>


</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add more details. Can u post the whole files?
Anyway, I think your issue is related to navigating from a screen in a navigator to another screen in another navigator. If both screens don't live on the same navigator, you should use:

```
navigation.navigate('NavigatorName', {
  screen: 'ScreenName',
  params: {item: item},
});
```

instead of

```
navigation.navigate('ScreenName', {item: item});
```

Answer (score -1):

Found out what was wrong. I tried using navigation.navigate('ScreenName') with passing navigation into the function at the top of drawerContent and it worked

Comment: This answer is more of a comment. Post details of the solution including the codes.